# How can I use align to pixel grid without messing up the outline view in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, grids

In Adobe Illustrator there is the feature of using 'Outline View'. It shows you the wireframes of your objects so you can see that they are properly aligned.

When I use 'Pixel Preview' I can see what the result is going to be if I export it to bitmap. So when a line of 1 px of width is not positioned at an exact pixel, there will be a blurry line. 
I use the checkbox 'Align to pixel grid' in the Transform panel to repair this.

But, here comes my surprise, when I change to 'Outline View' my lines are not properly aligned anymore.

How can I use this function without messing up the outline view in Adobe Illustrator??[image: Align to pixel grid results in a sharp image but messy outline view]

Comment: This belongs on GraphicDesign.SE (if they allow questions about tools).

Comment: If the file is destined for screen, and pixel preview shows things correct, why are you concerned with the outline mode?

Comment: Further to Scott's question, what alignment are you trying to do that can't just be done with the tools in the `align` window? This'll help us understand exactly what problem you're trying to solve - right now I don't quite get it, and I suspect that what you're seeing in Outline View is more of an artifact of Outline View's conversion to outlines itself than anything about your actual document.

Answer (score 1):

The reason not all the lines are aligned is because the box needed to be offset slightly so the fill was still a pixel boundary. In other words, it's working exactly as it needs to in order for everything to be aligned correctly.